# Stopping a .push with an if statement

Tags: arrays, if-statement, push, draw

This is a simple raindrop program for my course I need to complete. I want to tell the program if there are
`25` arrays of both `yPositions` and `xPositions` to stop pushing raindrop arrays with an `if` statement.

```
var xPositions = [random(0, 400)]; //Raindrop randomized X position 
var yPositions = [0]; Raindrop Y position

draw = function() {
    background(204, 247, 255);

    noStroke();
    fill(0, 200, 255);

    for (var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++) {
        ellipse(xPositions[i], yPositions[i], 10, 10); //raindrop loop

        if (yPositions[i] > 405) { //Duplicates the raindrops each time a raindrop hits a Y position of 405
            yPositions[i] = -10;
            xPositions[i] = random(0, 400);
            yPositions.push(i);
            xPositions.push(i);
            yPositions[i] += 5;

        } 

        if xPositions.length === 25 {
            this is where i want to tell the program to stop pushing both xPositions
            and yPositions if there are 25 arrays* /
        }

        yPositions[i] += 5;

    }

};
```

Well I don't really try anything specific since I don't really know what is required to be done. I'm new to coding so.